# Wake the Reflections and Young Pyromancer

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I think i got this right, but I'd like to make a sanity check.

If you cast [Wake the Reflections](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wake%20the%20Reflections) with [Young Pyromancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Young%20Pyromancer) in play, the pyromancer's trigger will resolve first, so that you will get a token to populate even if you originally had none, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. **When a "Whenever you cast" trigger is triggered, the ability will go on the stack above the spell that caused it, meaning it will be resolved first.**

Here's the sequence of play.

- I cast [Wake the Reflections](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wake%20the%20Reflections). Populate does not require selecting a target, so I don't have to make any choices about it when the spell goes on the stack.
- [Young Pyromancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Young%20Pyromancer)'s ability triggers ("Whenever you cast") and goes on the stack. This puts it above Wake the Reflections on the stack.
- (Both players pass, so the top of the stack resolves.) We resolve Young Pyromancer's ability, creating an Elemental token.
- (Both players pass, so the top of the stack resolves.) We resolve Wake the Reflections. I make a new token of any type I already have, including the 1/1 red Elemental I got a second ago.

Comment: I have a new deck idea... and the only rare I'll need is that new theros god, Purphoros. Mwahahahah

Comment: If populate said "target token", then this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @GendoIkari Targets are chosen as part of casting the spell, yes.